# Mysql remove stored escape character

Tags: mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

Due to a coding error by a prior dev I've discovered we have a mysql table that has a bit of data that has an extra escape character.

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\' FROM title)
```

I've tried the above but it obviously throws an error, and I've tried '\\'.  How do I get mysql to treat the backslash literally on it's own?

Comment: I am realizing I'm using the wrong function.  I should be using replace instead, in which '\\' does work.  I'm sorry I wasted peoples time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
update mytable SET title = TRIM(TRAILING '\\' FROM title)
```

Comment: This is right and should work, but he said he's already tried escaping the backslash.

Comment: Thought I'd try writing it out completely since I ran a test with the exact same statement and it worked.

Comment: When I do a select statement SELECT *  FROM mytable WHERE title LIKE '%\\%' does not work whereas '%\\\\%' does work